# How to change the scope of a Google Compute Engine service account to write data to a Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, service-accounts

There is an instance running on GCE and there is a GCS bucket in same project. But I am not able to write data to it. How can I write data from a VM instance to the storage bucket?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Update: **as of 15 Dec 2016**, the feature [`setServiceAccount`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) is now in **beta**:

> You can change the service account and/or access scopes of an existing instance if you want to run as a different identity, or you determine that the instance needs a different set of scopes to call the required APIs. For example, you can change access scopes to grant access to a new API or change an instance so that it runs as a service account you created instead of the Compute Engine Default Service Account.
>
> To change an instance's service account and access scopes, the instance must be temporarily stopped. To stop your instance, read the documentation for [Stopping an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/stopping-or-deleting-an-instance). After changing the service account or access scopes, remember to [restart the instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/restarting-an-instance#restarting_a_stopped_instance).

The [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) provides instructions for how to use this feature using the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), `gcloud` CLI tool, as well as API. Here's an example using `gcloud`; see the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes) for more info.

> ```
> gcloud beta compute instances set-scopes [INSTANCE_NAME] \
>      --service-account [SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL] \
>      [--no-scopes | --scopes [SCOPES,...]]
> ```

---

**Previous answer (valid prior to 15 Dec 2016):**

You can't change the scopes of a running VM instance. You can either:

- [create a new instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) (possibly reusing the disks of your current instance) with the right scopes specified at creation time, e.g.:

  ```
  gcloud compute instances create [...] --scopes storage-rw
  ```
- if you want to use `gsutil` manually from inside the VM, you can run [`gsutil config`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config) inside the VM and authenticate by following its prompts
- if you are planning to use an automated tool using Google APIs, use a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication?hl=en#service_accounts)

Answer (score 7):

There is pending improvement:

[Google Cloud Platform Ability to change API access scopes](https://googlecloudplatform.uservoice.com/forums/302595-compute-engine/suggestions/13101552-ability-to-change-cloud-api-access-scopes-on-launc)

but no due date stated yet. Stay tuned.