# Docker-Machine do not work with Google Cloud service account

Tags: docker, docker-machine, google-compute-engine

I Create a google compute instance with service account

```
gcloud --project my-proj compute instances create test1 \
--image-family "debian-9" --image-project "debian-cloud" \
--machine-type "g1-small" --network "default" --maintenance-policy "MIGRATE" \
--service-account "gke-build-robot@myproj-184015.iam.gserviceaccount.com" \
--scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform" \
--tags "gitlab-runner" \
--boot-disk-size "10" --boot-disk-type "pd-standard" --boot-disk-device-name "$RESOURCE_NAME" \
--metadata register_token=mytoken,config_bucket=gitlab_config,runner_name=test1,gitlab_uri=myuri,runner_tags=backend \
--metadata-from-file "startup-script=startup-scripts/prepare-runner.sh"
```

Log to instance though ssh: `gcloud compute --project "myproj" ssh --zone "europe-west1-b" "gitlab-shared-runner-pool"`

After install and configure docker machine. i try create instance:

```
     docker-machine create --driver google --google-project myproj test2
    Running pre-create checks...
    (test2) Check that the project exists
    (test2) Check if the instance already exists
    Creating machine...
    (test2) Generating SSH Key
    (test2) Creating host...
    (test2) Opening firewall ports
    (test2) Creating instance
    (test2) Waiting for Instance
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Operation error: {EXTERNAL_RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND  The resource '1045904521672-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' of type 'serviceAccount' was not found. []}
```

1045904521672-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com is my default account.
I don;t understand why it used. Because activated is gke-build-robot@myproj-184015.iam.gserviceaccount.com

```
gcloud config list
[core]
account = gke-build-robot@myproj-184015.iam.gserviceaccount.com
disable_usage_reporting = True
project = novaposhta-184015
Your active configuration is: [default]

 gcloud auth list
                      Credentialed Accounts
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
*       gke-build-robot@myproj-184015.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Can some one explain me, what i do wrong?

Comment: I use 0.12 version of docker machine.
0.13 version do not work, always return segmentation failed.

Comment: i see that $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS is empty.
And i can't understand, where gcloud credentials stored

Comment: Full scripts can be found here https://github.com/GrigorievNick/gitlab-runner-gce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was double problem.

- First of all, docker-machine can't work with specific service account, at least in 0.12 and 0.13 version.
- Docker+Machine google driver have only `scope` parameter and can't get specific one.
  So Instance where docker+machine was installed is work fine with specified `sa`. **But instance that was created with docker+machine, must have default service account**.
  And when during debug, I turn off it.
  I've got this error as a result.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue ([bosh-google-cpi-release issue 144](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/bosh-google-cpi-release/issues/144)) suggests somehow the

> This error message is unclear, particularly because the credentials which also need to be specified in the manifest may be associated with another account altogether.
>
> The default `service_account` for the `bosh-google-cpi-release` is set to "`default`" if it is not proactively set by the bosh manifest, so this will happen anytime you use `service_scopes` instead of a `service_account`.

While you are not using `bosh-google-cpi-release`, the last sentence made me double-check the [`gcloud` reference page](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/), in particular [`gcloud compute instance create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--service-account).

> A service account is an identity attached to the instance. Its access tokens can be accessed through the instance metadata server and are used to authenticate applications on the instance.
>   The account can be either an email address or an alias corresponding to a service account. You can explicitly specify the Compute Engine default service account using the '`default`' alias.
>
> If not provided, the instance will get project's default service account.

It is as if your service account is either ignored or incorrect (and falls back to the project default's one)

See "[Creating and Enabling Service Accounts for Instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances)" to double-check its value:

> Usually, the service account's email is derived from the service account ID, in the format:

```
[SERVICE-ACCOUNT-NAME]@[PROJECT_ID].iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Or try [setting first the service scope and account](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31868837/6309).

Comment: This service account work fine.
I change it's name, because of corporate policy reason.
I don't want create alias to my default service account.
I want use docker machine with specific one.
Error message just show that docker+machine use not specified account, but default one. And i turn off it for some time. Because i note that it's used in place, where i WANT USE SPECIFIC ACCOUNT, NOT DEFAULT.

Comment: I don't need set service account to instance.
 gcloud compute instances describe gitlab-shared-runner-pool -> serviceAccounts:
- email: gke-build-robot@myproj-184015.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  scopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

Every thing fine from gce prospect, but by some reaso docker+machine want use default service account.

Comment: @user2870704 yes, that is the issue indeed. I thought that forcing the service account explicitly would improve the situation.

Comment: That's does not help.
How can explicitly specify the Compute Engine default service account using the 'default' alias. I need create sa, with `default` in name?

Comment: Ok my UI do not work.
But i'am reEnable API with gcloud ctl.
And this help.