# Access GS using Docker with GCloud Python API without a service account on VM

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform

I need to access Google Storage from a Docker image running in a VM. I'm running the VM without a service-account (security reasons) and starting a Docker image with GCloud Python API installed. When I'm trying to connect on GS, in my case to read some raw data, it's throwing this exception:

`Failed to retrieve http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/?recursive=true from the Google Compute Engine metadata service. Status: 404`

When I start up the VM with the service account, I can call use the GCP Python API with success.

Example of code not working:

`from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
for bucket in client.list_buckets():
   print(bucket)`

There's someone that faced this problem already? Is it possible to use GCP Python without service account?

[Pyhton Lib]
https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/client.html

Thanks,

Comment: In your code you doesn't specify a project id: `client = storage.Client()` Do you have setup "GCLOUD_PROJECT" as env variable when you start docker container ?

Comment: The project is configured properly. Even without passing this argument. If I run ```client.project``` shows me the right project name. But I tested your suggestion and still not working.

Comment: Do you check the right scope when you create your VM ?

Comment: I'll post here this answer just in case it helps since you never answered to Alexandre: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31855049/how-to-change-the-scope-of-a-google-compute-engine-service-account-to-write-data